# Laravel deployment issue on Linux sharded server

Tags: laravel, deployment

I have built my Laravel application on a Windows10 machine. For the deployment on my Linux server (shared server), i have followed this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4VIWOj_9dA

My Application works fine on my developpement computer. The method of the tutorial works fine on window machine. But when i made the deployment on Linux with the same package i have tested on my Windows machine, for a page that does not call a controller, it works but for any page where a controller is called, i receive this error message (an example for a page that requires the kitContrller):

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\kitController] does not exist.
```

My problem is that the target controller existes in the indicated folder without any case problem but the message says that it does not existe.

Please, help.

Comment: Did you check like the case sensitivity there on the naming and maybe do a composer dump-autoload if you change the naming; I think the operating system have different thoughts on the case sensitivity :P

Answer (score 0):

After some other verifications, i saw that the problem was in my router: In the router, i have written the name of the Controller with lower case (Example: kitController in stead of KitController.

k(Lower case) in stead of K(upper case): That was the problem. I have changed things and it works fine.

Thank u for suggestions.